# Find MIN and MAX Database Backup duration

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup

I have this query to find the duration of backups taken which I want to run against registered servers in CMS across the entire enterprise.

The problem though, is how to find only the `MIN` and `MAX` duration per database rather than the runtime of all of the backups.

I've messed around a lot with `MIN` and `MAX` but have yet to find the correct combination.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname

SET @dbname = NULL 

SELECT database_name AS [Database]
    , backup_start_date AS [Backup Started]
    , backup_finish_date AS [Backup Finished]
    , backup_size AS [Backup Size]
    , compressed_backup_size AS [Compressed Backup Size]
    , CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, backup_start_date, backup_finish_date) AS int))/3600 AS varchar) + ' hours, ' 
     + CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, backup_start_date, backup_finish_date) AS int))/60 AS varchar)+ ' minutes, '
     + CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, backup_start_date, backup_finish_date) AS int))%60 AS varchar)+ ' seconds' AS [Total Time]
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
WHERE [type]!='L' 
    AND database_name IN (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases)
GROUP BY database_name
    ,backup_start_date
    ,backup_finish_date
    ,backup_size
    ,compressed_backup_size;
```

Code sourced from [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1747/how-to-find-out-how-long-a-sql-server-backup-took/).

Comment: what do you mean by "min" and "max"?  Are you talking about the earliest backup taken and the latest backup taken?

Comment: The shortest and longest amount of time a backup took.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` aggregate to get the min and max rows, then show only those rows:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d.name
        , bs.backup_start_date
        , bs.backup_finish_date
        , DurationInSeconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, bs.backup_start_date, bs.backup_finish_date)
        , RnMin = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.name 
               ORDER BY DATEDIFF(SECOND, bs.backup_start_date, bs.backup_finish_date) ASC)
        , RnMax = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.name 
               ORDER BY DATEDIFF(SECOND, bs.backup_start_date, bs.backup_finish_date) DESC)
    FROM msdb.dbo.backupset bs
        INNER JOIN master.sys.databases d ON bs.database_name = d.name
)
SELECT cte.name
    , cte.backup_start_date
    , cte.backup_finish_date
    , cte.DurationInSeconds
FROM cte
WHERE cte.RnMax = 1
    OR cte.RnMin = 1
ORDER BY cte.name
    , cte.backup_start_date;
```